# How to link files in gcc

Tags: c, linker-errors, libcurl

So I have installed curl4 and when I type in the global preparation like 'curl_global_init() and give it the 'CURL_GLOBAL_ALL' I get back this error:

> /tmp/ccUFNPUa.o: In function 'main':
>   curl.c:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to 'curl_global_init'
>   [Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Is that because I have not linked the library to the linker? If not how do I link it to the compiler/linker?

I'm using C. and the compiler is gcc.

Comment: did you ccompile with `-lcurl` option ?

Comment: Thank you for the help Mr VoidPointer it now works :)

Answer (score 3):

Add `-lcurl` to your `gcc` command. This will link your application with the curl library, specifically, `libcurl.a`.

e.g - `gcc myfile.c -lcurl -o myprogram`

More information can be found at the [GCC online documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html)